# Accessing phpldap admin from outside

Tags: php, ldap

I am trying to set up ldap on my server. I can access it from inside my cluster on the local url `http://192.168.0.0/myorgldap`. However, I would like to access it from outside the network. I can not find a way to redirect this url as I don't know which port to redirect on my router. What port would that be?

Comment: `http://` ... port 80?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could access by correcting the url : it is a secure one, so using https://@IP-internet-box/myorgldap has been working (opening port 80 too).